# how can I use jQuery to SELECT from different id's of objects of a certain type?

Tags: jquery, select

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
```

I have many buttons on my page.
there is one type of buttons are being generated automatically and each one receives a different id (gh_btn1, gh_btn2, gh_btn3...and so on.)

this seem to work only if I change `"#btn1"` to `"button"` (so it recognise all the buttons on the page, but I want it to recognise only all the buttons that are serving a certain purpous (the ones with the "gh_btn..." id

I saw someone doing something like that:
$("#bunnot_1,#button_2,#button_3").click

but that is limiting me incase I have many buttons.

is there something like $("#btn"*).click or something?

thank you!
this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn1").click(function() {
                $.post("test_post.php", {
                        name: "Jake",
                        city: "NY"
                    },
                    function(data, status) {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        $("#btn").val(data);
                        $("#txt").val(obj.name);
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button>Set back</button>

    <input type="button" id="btn1" style="color: red" value="111">a</input>

    <input type="button" id="btn2" style="color: red" value="222">a</input>

    <input id=txt value="333">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's working for me. Maybe the problem is 
$("#btn").val(data);
should be
$("#btn2").val(data);
there is no element with id btn.

Comment: you don't have any element with the id `btn` in your code

Comment: What error do you get? What does the console tell you?

Comment: the code works, what is the issue?

Comment: I have edited the question. thank you. hope its more clear now.
I need the "btn" id to be something like "btn_"* so it could recognize what button id was clicked among all the buttons I have

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `^=` (starts with) attribute selector:

```
$("[id^='btn']")
```

Answer (score 0):

ok - here is an answer:
I have 3 (or even 100) buttons with different IDs
(and I want to handle only the buttons of a certain type (for example only the "form" buttons and not the "like" buttons) - Im doing this by defining a certain class to each one of them:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".clshlpbtn").on('click',function(e){
var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
 alert("The id of the button that was clicked: "+id);
$.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
      name: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){

    //parsing the data should come here:
    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    //$("#"+id).val(obj.name);
    //etc.

    if (id=="btnhlp-1")
       $("#"+id).attr("style","color:red");
    $("#"+id).val(data);
    });
});




});
</script>
</head>
<body>
```